react ts(2742) cannot be named without a reference
i got this error ts(2742) cannot be named without a reference for all rtk query actions, how i can fix it?
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const postsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "url" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getChaptersList: builder.query({
      query: () => "/chapters-list/",
    }),
    getChapter: builder.query({
      query: (chapter:string) => `/chapters-list/${chapter}/`,
    }),
  }),
});


export const { 
    useGetChaptersListQuery,
    useGetChapterQuery 
} = postsApi;


The inferred type of 'useGetChapterQuery' cannot be named without a reference to '../../../node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react/buildHooks'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.ts(2742)



What happens if you do this instead of the way you are currently exporting?
export const useGetChapterQuery = postsApi.endpoints.getChapter.useQuery

@RobertRendell same error

Are you using Typescript? Have you typed your endpoints, e.g. builder.query<ResultType, QueryArg>? Your getChapter endpoint might look like getChapter: builder.query</* ResultType */, string>({ ... }),. What versions of react-redux and @reduxjs/toolkit are you using, and if you have any @types/...... for them what those are as well? (maybe just share your package.json file?)

It's easy to solve by changing the "moduleResolution" in 'tsconfig.json' or 'tsconfig.app.json' (depending on your project version) from 'Bundler' to 'Node'. 
Example of tsconfig.app.json

Please explain, why your suggestion solves the problem when the error states, that "a type annotation is necessary".

Am used vite latest version, i set a little older vite version and now i don't have this ts error :]

There are two solutions:

Assert "any" type while exporting from the Redux API file:

export const { useLoginMutation, useSignUpMutation } = baseApi as any;


You can export baseApi and call the hooks like this:

import baseApi from '../redux/api/baseApi';

const [login] = baseApi.useLoginMutation();


In my case, I only removed the following "composite" option from my tsconfig.json file.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": false
  }
}

You can also try it with the "declaration" option, source.
